# Testing Android support on older versions

Tags: android, testing, android-support-library

I am making application with target SDK set to 17 and min to 8.

So for some features I have to use Support library v4

Question is how can I test it works on older devices?

I am testing on my phone - which has 4.2.2; and I don't have others with older ones

Will creating emulator with 2.3.3 be true test?

tnx

---

Update

Just for example: I use Fragment in my code (from android.app, not from support library) - even if my minSDK is 4 - I don't see any warnings...should I?

Comment: the minSdk will guarantee the compatibility with Android API 8. Do not suppress any "new api" warning of Lint and you and your app will do good

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is an emulator (not a simulator) so it is very similar to running your code on the corresponding phone.
Another good practice is to run the Lint tests from times to times, they can detect many common mistakes in your code (including compatibility).
Your ide (both Eclipse & Android Studio plugins do this) will also display warning for obvious calls to functions that don't exist at your chosen min API level.

Answer (score 0):

> Most of the time emulator  behave same if we consider layout view and
>   other stuff like look and feel  performance , but that can be
>   difference in case of speed performance and sound quality

.

I found one online tool which are providing that service  please go through that link , https://appthwack.com

Answer (score 0):

apache lint (from tools) is the answer - shows all problems